# 2amigos Datepicker is not working with AdminLTE in yii2

Tags: yii2, adminlte

I'm using 2amigos datepicker in my application and it's working good throughout. Today I tried to apply AdminLTE theme to the application. I've added all the css, js in the asset file and uploaded them in the respective folders. No error in the browser console so far.
The first thing I notice is that the datepicker is not working. When I click on the calendar icon on the datepicker, the datepicker doesn't open.

Asset file

```
<?php

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main frontend application asset bundle.
 */
class DashboardAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css',
        'css/AdminLTE.min.css',
        'css/skins/_all-skins.min.css',
        'plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css',
        'plugins/morris/morris.css',
        'plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css',
        'plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css',
        'plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css',
        'plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js',
        'plugins/morris/morris.min.js',
        'plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
        'plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js',
        'plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js',
        'plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js',
        'plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js',
        'plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js',
        'plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js',
        'plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
        'plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js',
        'js/app.min.js',
        'js/dashboard.js',
        'js/demo.js',

    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

I'm using the datepicker like below -

```
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;

<?= $form->field($model1, 'startdate')->widget(
                    DatePicker::className(), [
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Start Date ...', 'id' => 'startdate1'],
                     'inline' => false,
 style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    ]
                    ]);?>
```

Comment: Your line beginning with "style=" looks like a copy/paste error from the 2amigos example; check their line starting with "template =>".

Comment: @sonofagun I've corrected the "style"... But still the same error.

Comment: Please correct the code above then.  Check the javascript files in your browser (Sources tab in Chrome); perhaps there's a mistaken path in your asset bundle.  Anyway, you shouldn't need to specify all those css and js paths - for example you have bootstrap in your depends so you don't need to specify css/bootstrap.min.css and js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js.